# Why power BI doesn't recognize Hebrew values while filtering?

Tags: powerbi

I have a table which I imported from Mysql server database.

one of the tables I'm working on, contains Hebrew values (which are presented completely fine), but when I'm trying to filter according those values, it can't find results, even though I can see there are rows answering the condition I filtered.

To make myself clear - I have a column named "communication type", and it has three optional value which are written with Hebrew letters, while trying to filter the rows according to one of the those three values, it doesn't find any row (No rows is fetched).

Would appreciate your help!